# Test string with a string list

Tags: javascript, arrays, list, typescript

I have a list of Id contained in an array :

```
var listId: string[] = [];
var newId: boolean;
for (let i in data.chunk) {
    listId.push(data.chunk[i].aliases[0]);
}
```

I then want to test my new Id with this whole list. If my new Id is in the list I want to return a false, and if it is not returned a true.

```
for(let i of listId) {
    if(member.userId !== listId[i]) {
      newid = true;
    }
    else {
      newId = false;
    }
  }
```

I do not see how to do it .. My proposed solution does not work

Comment: Have tried using debugger?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
    if(listId.indexOf(member.userId) !== -1)
     {
      newId = false; 
     }else
      {
       newid = true;
      }
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't `return false` in else, **do it outside for-loop** once you are sure that items are processed.

```
for(let i of listId) {
    if(member.userId !== listId[i]) {
      return true;
    }
  }
return false;
```

Otherwise unless first item's check `return true`, your method will always `return false` without checking the rest of the items, since it hasn't got the chance to iterate and process rest of the items.

> Yes but I need a variable boolean who return true or false. Like newId
>   because after I do that `if(member.userId !== userId && newId) { ... }`

Using **flag**

```
var flag = false;
for(let i of listId) {
    if(member.userId !== listId[i]) {
      flag = true;
      break;
    }
  }
return flag;
```

Comment: Yes but I need a variable boolean who return true or false. Like `newId` because after I do that `if(member.userId !== userId && newId) { ... }`

Comment: @Floriane Not sure why you need a flag, but check the updates.

Answer (score 0):

This will work too

```
return !listId.some(id => member.userId === id);
```

Comment: Yes but I need a variable boolean who return true or false. Like `newId` because after I do that `if(member.userId !== userId && newId) { ... }`

Comment: Well, you can do this then:

var newId = !listId.some(id => member.userId === id);

Answer (score 0):

```
public listId: string[] = [];

for(let i of this.listId) {
    if(member.userId !== this.listId[i]) {
      newid = true;
    }
    else {
      newId = false;
    }
  }
```

your array not accessing outside foreach loop. you need this operator to access whole value. hope you help.